# Replaced BR tag with a comma but adds a space after text

Tags: html, css

I noticed that a space is added when I replace BR tag with a comma in the text:

HTML:

```
<div>
one first
<br class="hey">
two second
<br class="hey">
three third
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hey {
  content: '';
}
.hey:before {
  content: ', ';
}
```

**Result**: one first , two second , three third

**The result I want**: one first, two second, three third

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tk4f7n9b/

PS: I can only use CSS. I can't inject or change any code into HTML. I can add an external JS file though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why there is a space, is because there are new lines between elements.
What you can do is use negative left margin:

```css
.hey {
  content: '';
}
.hey:before {
  content: ',';
  margin-left: -0.2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
one first
<br class="hey">
two second
<br class="hey">
three third
</div>
```

Comment: OH wow. Didn't think of it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[@vanovm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72674339/14148586) is a good CSS only solution.
Using an **external JS file**: change the `<br>` elements to be on the same line as the text nodes.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('div')

el.innerHTML = `<div>
one first<br class="hey">
two second<br class="hey">
three third
</div>`
```

```css
.hey {
  content: '';
}
.hey:before {
  content: ', ';
}
```

```html
<div>
one first
<br class="hey">
two second
<br class="hey">
three third
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a css property which can make <br> to be in the same line so that the new line doesn't create a space?